# Is there any GUI keyboard layout customizer?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I know I can have my own keyboard layout with [XKB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions), but the process is cumbersome.

Is there any GUI SW to customize the keyboard layout (for example for swapping keys)?

Preferably for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: if you were using the MATE Desktop, there is a native `mate-keyboard-properties` (also available in the Applications menu as "Keyboard" )... I have had no luck finding something similar for gnome... I do think there are a few others on other environments though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Input-remaper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper) was the answer.

Install some APT dependencies

```
sudo apt install git python3-setuptools gettext
```

Clone the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper.git
```

As a safety precaution scan it with clamscan before sudoing it

```
sudo apt install clamav -y
clamscan input-remapper/ --recursive
```

Install it

```
cd input-remapper && ./scripts/build.sh
sudo apt install ./dist/input-remapper-1.4.1.deb
```

[image]